# Integer Solutions for Inequality

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many integer solutions are there to the equation

\begin{equation} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 =132 \end{equation}
provided that
\begin{equation} x_1 > 0 \text{ and } x_2,x_3,x_4 ≥ 0? \end{equation}
and with the restriction that \begin{equation}x_4 < 17\ ?\end{equation}

My teacher told us the answer was # of total solutions - # of solutions with $x_4≥17$: C(134,4) - C(117,3).

I don't see where the C(134,4) comes from.

Comment: This looks like it's a homework question. What have you attempted?

Comment: See [partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics) could also be helpful for you.

Comment: First part is the same as $x_1 \ge 0$ and sum 132. Last part is (as above) - ($x_4 \ge 17$), and you can compute that the same way. Check out [stars and bars]( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of this as distributing 132 identical balls into 4 numbered boxes, where you have to put at least one ball in box 1 and cannot put more than 16 balls in box 4.

Since you have at least one ball in box 1, that means you have 131 balls left to distribute among the 4 boxes; and this is the number of ways to arrange 131 balls and 3 dividers, which is $\binom{134}{3}$.  Then you must subtract the distributions where there are at least 17 balls in box 4, which means there are 114 balls left to distribute; so there are $\binom{117}{3}$ ways to do this.

Therefore there are $\binom{134}{3}-\binom{117}{3}$ solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain where the C(134,3) comes from.

Consider a more simple question: number of **non-negative** integer solutions to the equation \begin{equation} x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 131 \end{equation}

This question [falls within the definition](http://howtocombi.com/number-of-integral-solutions.html) of "combinations with repetition".

In "combinations with repetition" ([I call it Basket](http://howtocombi.com/combinations-with-repetition-1.html)) you group **n** items into variations of size **k**: $\binom{\binom{n}{k}}{}$

However you can use the Basket formula to distribute **k** items among **n** places. For example:

distribute 131 sticks among 4 boxes: $\binom{\binom{131}{4}}{}$

This can be transformed to $\binom{131 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{134}{3}$